# Any support for Motoman HC10?

Tags: ros, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently performing a benchmark for collaborative robots using ROS. I have been searching but I cannot find support for this robot. Anybody can confirm this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271430/any-support-for-motoman-hc10?/) by [Walter_SG](https://answers.ros.org/users/29220/walter_sg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Motoman HC10 and HC20 are now available in the Motoman repo with the [motoman_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver) v1.9.0.
However some of the collaborative robot feather have limitations under ROS.  You should carefully review the associated note: [HC Robot Notes for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=HC+Notes.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [Eric Marcil](https://answers.ros.org/users/60004/eric-marcil/) with karma: 16 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-24**:
I've made this the accepted answer, as, as of `1.9.0`, HC robots are indeed supported by MotoROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'support' will depend a bit on what you are after: [motoman_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver) supports YRC1000 controllers starting from v1.5.0, but will not work with any of the collaborative features.

We also don't yet have a robot support package for the HC10, but those are relatively trivial to create.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1